# Convergence to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(x,t) = \infty$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ (but the convergence is not uniform). Is $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_a^b f(x,t) dx = \infty$ or do I need uniform convergence for this?

It is probably simple question, but I cannot remember a result that would give me this. Intuitively it should be enough even if we cannot change the order of limit and integral.

Comment: Are you integrating respect to $x$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous and measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly need something more than pointwise convergence.  Consider the case

$$f(x,t) = \min(t, (t^2+t)(tx-1)^2 - t^2)$$
where $\int_0^1 f(x,t)\; dx = -t/3 - 4/3$ for $t \ge 2$.  Note that $f(x,t) = t$ for $x=0$ and for $x > 2/t > 0$.

EDIT: If $f(x,t) \ge 0$ then it is true, because $$ \int_a^b f(x,t)\; dx \ge N m(\{x \in [a,b]: f(x,t) \ge N\})$$
(where $m$ is Lebesgue measure), and for any $N$, $m( \{x \in [a,b]: f(x,t) \ge N \}) \to b-a$ by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. It shows that I need something more than pointwise convergence and also an example of what could go wrong. In my application $f$ is actually non-negative. I'm wondering if this enough?